# How to show icon always in taskbar when there is no visible form available

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have a systray application without any taskbar icon. Nowdays most systray icons are hidden and I want to make an easier access to app.

There are no forms created with Application.FormCreate so Delphi cannot show icon itself.

How to show a normal app icon always on taskbar even when there is no visible form available?

I want to catch the click like this and when its clicked show the GUI with my custom function:

```
class procedure TTrayMain.HandleMessages(var Msg: TMsg; var Handled: Boolean);
begin

   if (Msg.wparam = SC_RESTORE ) then begin 
                 MenuPopup (popup,2);
                 Exit;
                 end;
```

Comment: Don't do this! There is a reason why Systray icons even exist. And that is to avoid clustering users taksbar with applications that have no window or have been minimized. And there is a reason why even systray icons are being hidden. And that is the shear fact that nowadays there are so many applications running in the background so that showing systray icon for each of them would also clutter the taskbar. I would recommend for searching of possibility to modify the systray settings for your application in order to keep icon of your application shown it this is even possible.

Comment: @J... And many fail to distinguish names from nouns: I can either configure windows, or Windows.

Comment: Thanks but the SysTray icon sometimes gets hidden,  so there must be some icon visible to users to use the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Taskbar button cannot exist without a window to represent. There are [only 3 ways](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031229-00/?p=41283) for a Taskbar button to be created:

- create a visible window with the `WS_EX_APPWINDOW` style
- create a visible top-level unowned window
- use [`ITaskbarList::AddTab()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-itaskbarlist-addtab)

All of them require a window.  But, that doesn't mean the *user* has to see the window. You can create a visible window with width/height set to 0 (some frameworks do this so no single app window owns the Taskbar button, but the button can show/hide the entire app as a whole), or move it offscreen. And then the window can respond to state changes as need, such as via the Taskbar button.

Otherwise, since your tray app likely has a hidden window to receive icon notifications, you can try using that window with `ITaskbarList`. I just don't know if it will actually do anything meaningful when the user clicks on the button.  So, consider changing your tray app to use a visible but unseen window for notifications, then it can have a Taskbar button without involving `ITaskbarList`.

Comment: Works nicely, however one small issue, when clicking Taskbar button with an invisible window, only every 2nd click  is sending SC_RESTORE msg that can be catched:

   if (Msg.wparam = SC_RESTORE ) then POPUP

Comment: I am reacting also to SC_MINIMIZE but there is some 3rd unknown message coming when clicking it while preview is flying above it

Comment: In delphi 7 its always =  with IFs..
 I am receiving these WPARAMS and LPARAMS  ; 
TTrayMain.HandleMessages:: w 80000006 l 000
TTrayMain.HandleMessages:: w 80000001 l 000
TTrayMain.HandleMessages:: w 80000001 l 000
TTrayMain.HandleMessages:: w 6FE2 l 767AC3D0
TTrayMain.HandleMessages:: w 80000006 l 000
TTrayMain.HandleMessages:: w 80000001 l 000
TTrayMain.HandleMessages:: w 6FB3 l 767AC3D0
TTrayMain.HandleMessages:: w 404B l 04B
-TTrayMain.HandleMessages:: w 80000006 l 000
TTrayMain.HandleMessages:: w 80000001 l 000
TTrayMain.HandleMessages:: w 80000005 l 004

Comment: Its still not catching 100% of clicks with this one;
   if (Msg.wparam = SC_RESTORE) or (Msg.wparam = SC_MINIMIZE) or (Msg.message = WM_SHOWWINDOW)  or (Msg.message = WM_ACTIVATEAPP) or (Msg.message = WM_SHOWWINDOW)  then begin

Comment: I will make a new ticket

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71146612/what-are-wm-messages-needed-to-react-to-all-clicks-of-application-icon-on-taskba

Comment: `SC_RESTORE`/`SC_MINIMIZE` are flags of the `WM_SYSCOMMAND` message only. You need to look at the `Msg.message` BEFORE looking at its `wParam`/`lParam`. It would help if your logging output the `Msg.message` value too, not just the `wParam`/`lParam`